# What is the difference between react-native's Share and react-native-share in npmjs

Tags: react-native, npm, difference, android-sharing

I want to implement share the screenshot of the current view in both ios/android. Dont know which one of these API's are better and why they both exist too.

Answer (score 1):

React Native's Share is a method of React Native like `static share(content, options)` that **Open a dialog to share text content.**
On that the `.open()` method allows a user to share a premade message via a social medium they choose.

For Further [React Native Share Documentation](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/)

On the other `react-native-share` is a package of npm. It is a simple tool for sharing messages and files with other apps.

For further [react-native-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share)

both act as same but one is a method and the other is a package. You can use both to share text or messages with others.

I hope it will beneficial for you to apply. and understanding that differences.

Comment: cool, so if you want to share anything other than text or URL you should use react-native-share. Thanks that really helps.